# Are there USB hubs that connect to an Ethernet port?

Tags: usb, ethernet, hub

I'm wondering whether such a device exists.

The following shows what I'm asking about:

```
+----------+            +---------+
|          |            |         +<----> USB #1
| Computer +<---------->+ USB Hub +<---------> USB #2
|          |  Ethernet  |         +<-----------------> USB #3
+----------+            +---------+
```

So the computer would connect via Ethernet to a device which "transforms" the TCP or UDP packets in USB signals. The advantage would be that we'd have full speed for all the USB's on a 10Gb network.

The USB #1/2/3 is where I'd connect my mouse, keyboard, stick drive, printer, etc.

Here is my complete list of devices at the moment:

- Keyboard
- Mouse 1 (middle mouse button)
- Mouse 2 (wheel)
- Printer
- Scanner
- Audio Device
- Phone (data transfers for video/pictures)
- USB Stick

I also have a need for USB Power to recharge the phone, although that's not mandatory. My server has only 4 ports on the back. There is one which is internal. And also it has two for the front panel, but it is on a head which is not compatible with the case cable connector.

One reason I need more ports now is that I do not have PS/2 connectors on this new server. My old one used the keyboard/mouse on its PS/2 connectors. Miscalculation on my part, although I did not expect the front panel connection issue.

Comment: There are, but what are you using it for? There may be a better way.

Comment: @JMY1000, I added some details about my specific situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Linux there is something called [USB over IP](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2018/208/Tutorial-USB-IP). There are is even a [tutorial on setting it up on Raspberry Pi](https://derushadigital.com/other%20projects/2019/02/19/RPi-USBIP-ZWave.html). So grab a 30$ single board computer and you are done. There was some Windows effort on this but it seems dead now.

Otherwise if the distance is not that big and your computer (a notebook presumably) supports it I would look into USB-C docking stations. Some of them are even integrated into displays. Or just a high-performance USB hub. Once I have seen an (expensive) USB 3.0 extender with active devices on both and which used about 30 meters of fiber.

Comment: I actually happen to have a Raspberry 3 B. 4 ports will be enough since it won't use one of my 4 ports on my server and USB 2 for those extra port is enough. Otherwise, I don't have a notebook, I have a _Supermicro X11DPH-T_. It offers 7 USB ports, but one is inside the box and two have a head which my case doesn't support... (I hope to resolve that one at some point...)

Comment: @AlexisWilke just FYI: the Pi uses a USB hub with Ethernet, so they all share a single USB high speed link. If that's not good I believe they changed it on the Pi 4 or use another SBC

Comment: As for the notebook part, I just wanted to cover all bases since many people come here with XY problems.

Comment: And out of sheer curiosity I looked through the manual for the supermicro. USB 4/5 looks like bog standard ATX internal USB 3.0 so you can get something meant for desktops, like a cable or something for the 5.25" bay, like this: https://www.newegg.com/p/N82E16812423205

Comment: Oh that Coboc device is interesting. Not quite what I'd like because outside of my memory stick I would prefer to connect things on the back. But that would be a good solution to have front USB connectors.

Comment: @AlexisWilke for back panel there similar headers which mount in the case's PCI slots, without using PCIe on the motherboard, but I couldn't find a decent link, here's one to a Polish shop so you know what you're looking for: https://www.ceneo.pl/28812940

Comment: A link to vendor's website: http://gembird.com/item.aspx?id=8075

Comment: But check the connector carefully, what little I know about server hardware says that it might look standard but be different and I didn't check in details

Comment: Yes, that USB 20 pin connector is exactly what I'd need to use those two ports! I had one of those on an old computer. I don't think I kept that cable, though.

Comment: @AlexisWilke the old one might have been a 2.0 port, with a different connector. And I heard somewhere that these connectors are hard to take out so be careful with that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if [this device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014ZOJX7W) is exactly what you need: "Anker 3-Port USB 3.0 HUB with 10/100/1000 Gigabit Ethernet Converter (3 USB 3.0 Ports, A RJ45 Gigabit Ethernet Port, Support Windows XP, Vista, Win7/8 [32/64 bit], Mac OS 10.6 and Above, Linux)"

Comment: I have a similar device, it goes from USB to Ethernet. I have a machine where the onboard Ethernet died. I was wondering whether there was the "opposite", where I have a connection to the Ethernet which gives me USB ports